# Registration and Login form not submitting

Tags: php, jquery

I have read thru almost all docs on this but cant seem to find a tailored solution to my problem. The registration and login form is with php5, mysqli, jquery and bootstrap, but it's not submitting to the database.

For register.php

```html
<?php require_once 'config.php'; ?>

<?php 
 if(!empty($_POST)){
  try {
   $user_obj = new Cl_User();
   $data = $user_obj->registration( $_POST );
   if($data)$success = USER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
   $error = $e->getMessage();
  }
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Registration Form</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="container">
  <?php require_once 'templates/ads.php';?>
  <div class="login-form">
   <?php require_once 'templates/message.php';?>
   
   <h1 class="text-center">Smart</h1>
   <div class="form-header">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
   </div>
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form-register" role="form" id="register-form">
    <div>
     <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"> 
     <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" > 
     <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> 
     <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password"> 
     <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-block bt-login" type="submit" id="submit_btn" data-loading-text="Signing Up....">Sign Up</button>
   </form>
   <div class="form-footer">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
      <a href="forget_password.php"> Forgot password? </a>
     
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      <a href="index.php"> Sign In </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- /container -->

 
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/register.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and for the register.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#register-form").validate({
  submitHandler : function(form) {
  //$('#submit_btn').attr('disabled','disabled');
  $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled','true');
   $('#submit_btn').button('loading');
   form.submit();
  },
  rules : {
   name : {
    required : true
   },
   email : {
    required : true,
    email: true,
    remote: {
     url: "check-email.php",
     type: "post",
     data: {
      email: function() {
       return $( "#email" ).val();
      }
     }
    }
   },
   password : {
    required : true
   },
   confirm_password : {
    required : true,
    equalTo: "#password"
   }
  },
  messages : {
   name : {
    required : "Please enter name"
   },
   email : {
    required : "Please enter email",
    remote : "Email already exists"
   },
   password : {
    required : "Please enter password"
   },
   confirm_password : {
    required : "Please enter confirm password",
    equalTo: "Password and confirm password doesn't match"
   }
  },
  errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
   $(element).closest('div').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
  },
  highlight : function(element) {
   $(element).closest('div').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest('div').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    $(element).closest('div').find('.help-block').html('');
  }
 });
 
 
});
```

and this is for the user.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * This User will have functions that hadles user registeration,
 * login and forget password functionality
 */
class Cl_User
{
 /**
  * @var will going contain database connection
  */
 protected $_con;
 
 /**
  * it will initalize DBclass
  */
 public function __construct()
 {
  $db = new Cl_DBclass();
  $this->_con = $db->con;
 }
 
 /**
  * this will handles user registration process
  * @param array $data
  * @return boolean true or false based success 
  */
 public function registration( array $data )
 {
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
   
   // Trim all the incoming data:
   $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);
   
   
   
   // escape variables for security
   $name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['name'] );
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['password'] );
   $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['confirm_password'] );
   
   
   // Check for an email address:
   if (filter_var( $trimmed_data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['email']);
   } else {
    throw new Exception( "Please enter a valid email address!" );
   }
   
   
   if((!$name) || (!$email) || (!$password) || (!$cpassword) ) {
    throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
   }
   if ($password !== $cpassword) {
    throw new Exception( PASSWORD_NOT_MATCH );
   }
   $password = md5( $password );
   $query = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, email, password, created) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$email', '$password', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
   if(mysqli_query($this->_con, $query)){
    mysqli_close($this->_con);
    return true;
   };
  } else{
   throw new Exception( USER_REGISTRATION_FAIL );
  }
 }
 /**
  * This method will handle user login process
  * @param array $data
  * @return boolean true or false based on success or failure
  */
 public function login( array $data )
 {
  $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
   
   // Trim all the incoming data:
   $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);
   
   // escape variables for security
   $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['email'] );
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['password'] );
    
   if((!$email) || (!$password) ) {
    throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
   }
   $password = md5( $password );
   $query = "SELECT user_id, name, email, created FROM users where email = '$email' and password = '$password' ";
   $result = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
   $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   mysqli_close($this->_con);
   if( $count == 1){
    $_SESSION = $data;
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    return true;
   }else{
    throw new Exception( LOGIN_FAIL );
   }
  } else{
   throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * This will shows account information and handles password change
  * @param array $data
  * @throws Exception
  * @return boolean
  */
 
 public function account( array $data )
 {
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
   // Trim all the incoming data:
   $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);
   
   // escape variables for security
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['password'] );
   $cpassword = $trimmed_data['confirm_password'];
   $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['user_id'] );
   
   if((!$password) || (!$cpassword) ) {
    throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
   }
   if ($password !== $cpassword) {
    throw new Exception( PASSWORD_NOT_MATCH );
   }
   $password = md5( $password );
   $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$password' WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
   if(mysqli_query($this->_con, $query)){
    mysqli_close($this->_con);
    return true;
   }
  } else{
   throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * This handle sign out process
  */
 public function logout()
 {
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  header('Location: index.php');
 }
 
 /**
  * This reset the current password and send new password to mail
  * @param array $data
  * @throws Exception
  * @return boolean
  */
 public function forgetPassword( array $data )
 {
  if( !empty( $data ) ){
   
   // escape variables for security
   $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $data['email'] ) );
   
   if((!$email) ) {
    throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
   }
   $password = $this->randomPassword();
   $password1 = md5( $password );
   $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$password1' WHERE email = '$email'";
   if(mysqli_query($this->_con, $query)){
    mysqli_close($this->_con);
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "New Password Request";
    $txt = "Your New Password ".$password;
    $headers = "From: admin@smarttutorials.net" . "\r\n" .
      "CC: admin@smarttutorials.net";
     
    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
    return true;
   }
  } else{
   throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * This will generate random password
  * @return string
  */
 
 private function randomPassword() {
  $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
  $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
  $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
  for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
   $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
   $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
  }
  return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
 }
}
```

Comment: Pls can someone help look at my question.. At my codes.. What's wrong with it??